# Problem with writing UnitTests when multiple classes are in same file

Tags: java, unit-testing, package, inner-classes

I tried solving some coding challenges and ran into a problem, I copy the challenges and the tests to my pc and try to solve them, but this time I can't get the test to work properly and i assume the problem is that there are basically two top level classes in one file but only one of them is public (so the other one is ?default?) and since the test is in another package it cant find the second class.

so the situation is basically

File 1

```
package src.main.java;
public class A{
     public String doSomething(B objB){
          return objB.getName();
     }
}

class B{
     private String name;

     public B(String name){
        this.name=name;
     }

     public String getName(){
          return name;
     }
}
```

File 2

```
package src.test.java;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import src.main.java.A;

public class ATest{
     @Test
     public void test01() {
          assertEquals("Name1", A.doSomething(new B("Name1"));
     }
}
```

I tried making it an inner class, that worked, i also assume it works if I put the second class in its own file, and i assume it works if i put challenge and test file in the same package (class B is default visible):

File 1

```
package src.main.java;
public class A{
     public String doSomething(B objB){
          return objB.getName();
     }

     //make class B a public static inner class of A
     public static class B{
          private String name;

          public B(String name){
             this.name=name;
          }

          public String getName(){
               return name;
          }
     }
}
```

File 2

```
package src.test.java;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import src.main.java.A;

// I could also put class B in a seperate file
import src.main.java.B;

public class ATest{
     @Test
     public void test01() {
          assertEquals("Name1", A.doSomething(new A.B("Name1"));//call the inner class
     }
}
```

Those work, but the guy who wrote the challenge didn't have to do that, did he just have the challenge file and the test file in the same package?

Is there a way to make it work without making it an inner class, putting the second class in its own file or putting test and challenge in the same package?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It is normal operating procedure to have the tests and the classes under test in the same package.  Typically we would use maven and have a directory structure like the following:  `/src/main/java/package...` and `/src/test/java/package`.  Maven then will compile both those classes into one package and therefore the test can test all the public/protected/friendly attributes of a class.  I also recommend placing the `B` class in its own file.  It is strange that it is in the same `.java` file as `A`.

Comment: As @hooknc said -- do put each class in its own file, and learn about maven directory layout. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: I've been working with Java since 1997, in a variety of different organisations, and I can assure you of two things that have become industry standards. (1) Almost NOBODY puts multiple top-level classes in the same file.  There's no benefit to doing this.  Keep it to one file per top-level class. (2) Standard practice is for each unit test to be in exactly the same package as the class that it's testing. You can keep your unit tests in a separate source folder from your application classes, as described in the comment by @hooknc, so you don't need to use special packages to keep them separate.

Answer (score 0):

#### Bootstrap

I quickly bootstrapped a Spring Boot application using https://start.spring.io/ (to get the test set-ups) in my IDE and replicated your example using both `JUnit4` and `JUnit5` and both tests are successful.

#### Junit 4/5 test

```
package com.example;

public class A {
    public String doSomething(B objB){
        return objB.getName();
   }
}

class B{
    private String name;

    public B(String name){
       this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
         return name;
    }
}

package com.example;

//Replace imports accordingly for Junit4
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ATest {
     @Test
     public void test01() {
          assertEquals("Name1", new A().doSomething(new B("Name1")));
     }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine") //This is for JUnit4
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```